# SSRS Go to Report only if exists, else go else where

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I'm looking for a way to modify a Go to Report action.

I want to redirect a user to an existing report. If the Report doesn't exists on the server, redirect the user to a image or webpage instead.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to get this functionality within SSRS? or do you have some wrapping application that could handle this? (As far as I know, it will be difficult to make an SSRS report aware of whether other reports exist.)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do this in Report Builder. (SSRS)